# How can I tell if my LDAP authentications are using StartTLS?

Tags: ldap, starttls

I'm setting up a new OpenLDAP server on Ubuntu 12.04 with a copy of our current LDAP database. I've gotten most of the configuration down, I think, but I'm having trouble telling if the LDAP queries are encrypted or not. I suspect there may be a misconfiguration with the certificates, but I'm not sure how to tell.

Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Check your logs.
   (Or run the OpenLDAP clients in Verbose mode and they will tell you if they're using SSL.)
2. Don't trust your logs/clients.
   (Run wireshark or something similar and verify the traffic.)

Comment: Ran wireshark, and I can see my password clear as day. Thanks for your help!